# Parse File in React Native

Tags: ios, parse-platform, react-native

I am trying to upload the file to **parse**, which I am able to do via **REST API**. The file is a video in mp4 format.

After the file is uploaded I get a name and URL to that file, but I am not able to store that file in a `Parse` file object directly. With `RestAPI` I am able to do that.

Is there a way to upload a file from `react-native` (file can be asset-library:// or file absolute path) to parse as a Parse File and associate it with the Parse Object?

Comment: It is kind of hard to tell what the issue is based on your description. You are saying that you are not able to store the file. Are you getting any errors or why are you not able to store it? Also, it is really helpful if you provide some code to go along with this so that people can see if there is an issue in the code.